# Why ElGamal signature is insecure with nonrandom k?

Tags: signature, elgamal-signature

In ElGamal signature scheme like:

**Keygen:**
$\beta:=\alpha^a\bmod p$ where $\alpha$ and $p$ are large prime numbers. Public key is $(p,\alpha,\beta)$ and secret key is $a$.

**Sign:**
Choosing random $k$ such that $\gcd(k,p-1)=1$, calculating $r:=a^k\bmod p$ and $s:=k^{-1}\cdot(m-a\,r)\bmod(p-1)$; then we send $(m,r,s)$

**Verify:**
Calculating $v_1:=\beta^r\cdot r^s\bmod p$ and $v_2:=\alpha^m\bmod p$; then if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are equal the signature verifies.

In the booklet I'm reading for cryptography course it is said that if $k$ is non-random this signature scheme is insecure. What's the reason?

Comment: The equation really is $s:=k^{-1}\cdot(m-a\,r)\bmod(p-1)$, NOT $s:=k^{-1}\cdot(m-a\,r)\bmod p-1$, which reads as $s:=(k^{-1}\cdot(m-a\,r)\bmod p)-1$. If you don't understand why, write down a proof that the verification procedure works absent alteration of $(m,r,s)$

Comment: Hint for the question; what can an adversary do if s/he can _guess_ $k$, because it was chosen in too small a set? Independently: what can an adversary do if different messages get signed with the _same_ random $k$, because it was generated using a RNG with a broken source of true randomness?

Comment: Note: if your reference writes $s:=k^{-1}\cdot(m-a\,r)\pmod{p-1}$, well that's not quite standard notation, but it is understandable and the modulus is unambiguously $p-1$. In the [original question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/77240/1) I had been criticizing $\beta=\alpha^a\ (mod\ p)$ which (especially since it uses $=$ rather than $:=$ ) is quite interpretable as $\beta\equiv\alpha^a\pmod p$, which again only means that $p$ divides $\alpha^a-\beta$ and thus allows an infinity of choices for $\beta$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use constant $k$ in this scheme we can find the secret key like this:

We know $(m_1,r_1,s_1)$ and $(m_2,r_2,s_2)$ for two different plaintext, as k is constant $r_1=r_2=r$ so we have this equivalence:
$$s_1k-m_1\equiv-ar\equiv s_1k-m_1\ mod\ p-1 \Rightarrow (s_1-s_2)k \equiv m_1-m_2\ mod\ p-1$$

This equivalence has $d$ answer where $d=gcd(s_1-s_2,p-1)$, $d$ is usually small so we can find $k$ using brute force on $r\equiv \alpha^k\ mod\ p$.

Now we know $k$ we can caluculate $a$ using $a.r\equiv m_1-k.s_1$ equivalence. Number of answer for this equivalence is $gcd(r,p-1)$ by comparing $\beta$ and $\alpha^a$ we can find $a$.

Now we know secret key and sign every plain text we want and that's insecure.

Comment: I guess the first equation should be$$s_1\,k-m_1\equiv-a\,r\equiv s_2\,k-m_2\pmod{p-1}\implies(s_1-s_2)\,k \equiv m_1-m_2\pmod{p-1}$$Notice the change of some indices from $1$ to $2$, proper notation for equivalence modulo, use of thin space for multiplication rather than $.$ (when multiplication needs to be made explicit with a dot, a common choice is $\cdot$ )... Right-click on an equation then _Show Math As Tex Commands_ reveals the LaTex used. See [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555) for common idioms. Independently: a single signature with guessable $k$ allows attack.

Comment: ok thanks alot @fgrieu