# What is the purpose of $k \in \{2, \dots, p-2\}$ in ElGamal signatures on ${\mathbb{Z_{p}^{*}}}$?

Tags: public-key, signature, elgamal-signature

The question is mainly stated in the title. I had to do a refreshment on public key cryptography. The algorithms are pretty straightforward however, I always stumbled upon this question. Is it in order for the same message to be able to be signed with a different signature each time, like some kind of nonce?

P.S. I'm talking about textbook schemes.

Comment: Yes, It randomizes as in RSA-PSS. DSA,... Do you want distinguishable signature that someone noticed that you repeated?

Comment: [Why ElGamal signature is insecure with nonrandom k?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77240/18298)

Comment: the comment is spot-on and correct. you might want to write the formula including $k$ so that your question is comprehensible to others who are learning.

Comment: @kodlu I will update my question and answer it myself if no one else does when I have some spare time.